# Redis transaction by fixed number of clients

Tags: redis

I've already read multiple articles about redis transactions.
I have some lists that contains messages. And I use redis to generate auto-increment IDs for those messages.
Here's what I'm trying to do:

1. Read the counter value, then INCR it.
2. Put the incremented counter value in the `Id` field of the message, then serialize the message.
3. Push the serialized message into the list.

So the counter always holds the last message's ID in the corresponding list. I want to put a lock on the counter key so other requests cannot read and INCR the counter and push another message to the list that conflicts with the last ID.

Since I want to have a limited number of redis clients, WATCH MULTI EXCEC cannot be implemented, because it's the same client doing the transaction. And as far as I know WATCH MULTI EXCEC is for when you have multiple redis clients.

I want to know what is the correct approach for this problem. Should I use LUA scripts and let it serialize the message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lua is definitely the best option for creating an atomic logic unit that both reads and writes data.

In your case, however, I am not convinced that atomicity is really needed. Unless there is a strict requirement that the IDs have no gaps between them, you can just call [`INCRBY`](https://redis.io/commands/incrby) to obtain a new ID and then use it in serializing the message. Other messages will **not** get the same ID and the only "risk" is having your worker die before using that ID to serialize and store the message (hence creating a gap).

Comment: The "risk" that comes into my mind is that the last message in the list may not have the same ID as the counter.

Comment: Quite true, the order of messages in the list will not necessarily be correct without atomicity. If that's a requirement, go with Lua.